# How to disable KDE's brightness OSD?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, brightness, macbook-pro

I am using [lightum](https://github.com/poliva/lightum) to automatically control the screen's brightness depending on the surrounding light (on a Retina MacBook Pro).

The problem is, though, that KDE picks up the change and displays the OSD (same one that shows up when you change brightness with keyboard).

The brightness changes slightly every minute or so, making the OSD incredibly annoying. I would gladly get rid of it entirely if I could.

### Some research

I looked in KDE's notifications settings, found nothing. I also grep'd ~/.kde/share/config, found nothing. Google didn't help either.

Apparently setting the brightness by doing

```
# echo 4 > /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

doesn't bring up the OSD. From the source code, lightum seems to be setting brightness via dbus (`org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.setBrightness`).

Comment: As a workaround, I ended up modifying lightum to make it run as root as well and use the /sys/devices/.../brightness thing to set brightness instead. If anyone else finds this useful, you can use [my fork of lightum](https://github.com/vlad-alexandru-ionescu/lightum) - but make sure you start it up as root. I added this to visudo to be able to start it up automatically, with no password: `<my_user_name> ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/lightum`.

Comment: Type sudo su then edit the brightness by echo .. >

Comment: Please excuse the bump, but it seems that just running the search query: [org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.setBrightness](https://www.google.com/search?q=org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.setBrightness) will bring up the *bug* and (other) possible *solutions* ^^ Just btw. :)

Comment: Now this isn't kubuntu but should work all the same http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html

Comment: @Jessecast That website has an... unfortunate name :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by going into the Global Shortcuts control panel in System Settings and, under the "kded" section, remove the key binding for brightness up and brightness down.

Comment: That just disables the shortcut, not the OSD.

Comment: Refer http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html